# Power bi to Mysql on localhost

Tags: mysql, ssh, server, powerbi, system-administration

I want to connect power bi to a MySql db that is on an a remote server and allows only localhost connection. I know power bi does not support ssh by itself so I can't use it like in Workbench. Is there any workaround to connect powerbi to a remote mysql db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do it on my machine as follows:

1. Choose Get Data > SQL Server from the Home tab
2. Type `localhost` into the Server field
3. Click OK
4. Specify Credentials
5. Click Connect

Comment: this menus are in your powerbi application?

Comment: @StefanoMaglione Yes.

Comment: So your power bi and mysql are in two differents servers?

Comment: @StefanoMaglione Power BI is an application on my desktop PC and I have a localhost SQL server on my desktop PC. Not sure what you mean by different servers.

Comment: my fault, I have updated the question, I was not clear enough

Comment: Basically my db is on a remote server and only allows local connections.